# How to display another ViewController on SegmentedController value canged?

Tags: ios, swift

```
let segment : UISegmentedControl = {
        let segment = UISegmentedControl.init(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: SCREEN_HEIGHT-80, width: SCREEN_WIDTH-40, height: 40))
        segment.insertSegment(with: UIImage(named: "cgtab_pay"), at: 0, animated: true)
        segment.insertSegment(with: UIImage(named: "cgtab_service"), at: 0, animated: true)
        segment.insertSegment(with: UIImage(named: "cgtab_chat"), at: 0, animated: true)
        segment.insertSegment(with: UIImage(named: "cgtab_pay"), at: 0, animated: true)
        segment.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MySegmentControlAction), for: .valueChanged)
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        segment.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        
        return segment
    }()



    @objc func MySegmentControlAction(segment: UISegmentedControl) {
        if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
            
            segment.setImage(UIImage(named: "cgtab_pay_active"), forSegmentAt: 0)
            segment.setImage(UIImage(named: "cgtab_service"), forSegmentAt: 1)
            segment.setImage(UIImage(named: "cgtab_chat"), forSegmentAt: 2)
            segment.setImage(UIImage(named: "cgtab_pay"), forSegmentAt: 3)
            
            let rawPay = PayViewController.init()
            let payNavi = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: rawPay)
        
            //how to use rootViewController???            
            
        }else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
            
            segment.setImage(UIImage(named: "cgtab_pay"), forSegmentAt: 0)
            segment.setImage(UIImage(named: "cgtab_service_active"), forSegmentAt: 1)
            segment.setImage(UIImage(named: "cgtab_chat"), forSegmentAt: 2)
            segment.setImage(UIImage(named: "cgtab_pay"), forSegmentAt: 3)
            
            
            
        }else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2){
            
            segment.setImage(UIImage(named: "cgtab_pay"), forSegmentAt: 0)
            segment.setImage(UIImage(named: "cgtab_service"), forSegmentAt: 1)
            segment.setImage(UIImage(named: "cgtab_chat_active"), forSegmentAt: 2)
            segment.setImage(UIImage(named: "cgtab_pay"), forSegmentAt: 3)
            
            
            
        }else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 3){
            
            segment.setImage(UIImage(named: "cgtab_pay"), forSegmentAt: 0)
            segment.setImage(UIImage(named: "cgtab_service"), forSegmentAt: 1)
            segment.setImage(UIImage(named: "cgtab_chat"), forSegmentAt: 2)
            segment.setImage(UIImage(named: "cgtab_pay_active"), forSegmentAt: 3)
            
            
            
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches for achieving this 2 of them are:

### Child View Controllers

Add a container view below your segmented control that will be responsible for holding your child view controller's view let's say its `containerView`

```
lazy var controller1: UIViewController = {
    return self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Identifier1")
}()

lazy var controller2: UIViewController = {
    return self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Identifier2")
}()

lazy var controller3: UIViewController = {
    return self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Identifier3")
}()

func addChildController(controller: UIViewController) {
    self.addChildViewController(controller)
    controller.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
    self.containerView.addSubview(controller.view)
    
    controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    controller.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.leftAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    controller.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.rightAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
}

func removeCurrentChildController() {
    let currentChildController = self.childViewControllers.first
    currentChildController?.removeFromParentViewController()
    currentChildController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
}

@IBAction func segmentedControlValueChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    self.removeCurrentChildController()
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        self.addChildController(controller: self.controller1)
    } else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        self.addChildController(controller: self.controller2)
    }
}
```

It's just a basic example. Obviously you can improve it by making it interactive. for example put the child view controllers in a `scrollview` so user can also swipe left/right to switch to the desired controller (Don't forget to enable paging on `UIScrollView`)

### PageViewController

```
func setupPageController() {
    self.pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: [:])
    self.pageController.dataSource = self
    self.pageController.delegate = self
    
    self.addChildViewController(self.pageController)
    self.pageController.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
    self.contentView.addSubview(self.pageController.view)
    
    self.pageController.view.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges()
}

//MARK: UIPageViewControllerDataSource
extension OfferWalletViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let index = self.controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController), (index - 1) >= 0 {
            return self.controllers[index - 1]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let index = self.controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController), ((index + 1) < self.controllers.count) {
            return self.controllers[index + 1]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

//MARK: UIPageViewControllerDelegate
extension OfferWalletViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        debugPrint("pending controllers: \(previousViewControllers)")
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
        debugPrint("pending controllers: \(pendingViewControllers)")
    }
}
```

You can set your desired view controller like this:

```
self.pageController.setViewControllers([controller], direction: direction, animated: animated) { (completed: Bool) in
            
 }
```